# Visual Studio 2010 installer ignores ProgramFiles environment variables

Tags: windows, environment-variables, visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I am installing Visual Studio 2010 and am wondering why the installer doesn't respect environment variables.

ProgramFiles and related variables are configured for the D drive.

```
PS Env:\> dir program*

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ProgramFiles(x86)              D:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432                   D:\Program Files
ProgramData                    C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles                   D:\Program Files
```

But the Visual Studio installer defaults to "C:\Program Files (x86)" anyway.

I can change this to "D:\Program Files (x86)" manually but I do wonder whether Visual Studio just ignores environment variables and whether there is a good reason for that?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Which environment variables are you referring to? How did you change these? Installers are not looking at environment variables, there is a special API to get the location for folders like ProgramFiles, CommonProgramFiles, AppData, MyFiles, etc. This API gets its information from registry values. The environment variables are not the source for this information, they are set depending on the registry values.

Comment: The environment variables I am referring to show in the quoted PowerShell output. I thought the API gets the values stored in the environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that Visual Studio defaults to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ProgramFilesDir` registry key and not the environment variable.

EDIT: Added actual key, not just a variable reference.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by this?  `%ProgramFiles%` is an environment variable.  Which exact registry key are you referring to?

Comment: I do not know the exact registry key but I have run into this issue before.  It is probably in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion` Which the value there could be different than environment variables

Comment: Isn't that basically the machine version of the same variable? So VS uses the machine version, not the user version of the variable?